# How can i compare two localField with same form in mongoDB

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

i'm new to mongoBD. i have join two table using `$lookup`. i have two models `Posts` and `Savedpost`. I need to compare two field `postId` and `savedBy` i check mongoDb documentation for lookup and i try

```
Posts.aggregate([{
        $lookup: {
            from: Savedpost.collection.name, // collection name in db
            localField: "_id", // Post id from Post collection
            foreignField: "postId", // postId from Savedpost collection
            as: "isSaved"
        },
    }]).exec(function(err, students) {
        res.send(students)
    });
```

here i compare with only `postId` but i need to compare both fields `postId` and `savedBy` it is possible and how ?

Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is how to $lookup based on two fields:

```
 db.posts.aggregate([
 {
 $lookup: {
   from: "savedposts",
   let: {
     first: "$_id",
     second: "$savedby"
   },
   pipeline: [
    {
      $match: {
        $expr: {
          $and: [
            {
              $eq: [
                "$postid",
                "$$first"
              ]
            },
            {
              $eq: [
                "$saved",
                "$$second"
              ]
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  ],
  as: "result"
 }
}
])
```

Explained:

1. Add two temp variables from the post collection via let
2. In the lookup pipeline stage match based on the temporary variables to the  foreign collection lookup keys.

In the example:

first --> posts._id-->savedposts.postid

second --> posts.savedby-->savedposts.saved

[playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/PkjvSZx880Z)